# Do over-ridden functions affect dependent parent functions?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Imagine a `ParentContract` with functions `a()` and `b()`, where `b()` calls  `a()`

```
contract ParentContract{
    function a() {...}
    function b() {
        a()
    }
}
```

Now, I have a Child contract that over-rides function `a()` with `onlyOwner`

```
contract ChildContract is ParentContract{
    function a() onlyOwner() {
       super.a()
    }
}
```

In this case, have I modified function `b` as well to be `onlyOwner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have. When `ChildContract` is deployed, you have effectively overridden `ParentContract.a` so that it can never again be called as the non-owner. Every time you call `a()` you will be required to be owner. Because of this and the fact that `b()` simply calls `a()`, you will need to be the owner to successfully call `b()` in a transaction.